# Why there is single exception type for web::json

Tags: c++, json, exception, cpprest-sdk

Is there only one exception type available for cpprest json library.
I have seen
`web::json::json_exception`

as the single type.
Will it handle all kind of json exceptions?
Or any other types are available?

When searched in google for json exception I could see type different types of exceptions for nlohmann::json

Comment: its up to the library writers to decide how many types of exceptions they want to define. They could define none and throw strings, although this would be a bad idea.

Comment: Okay. So for cpprest web::json only one exception is there? Can you please help me to know whether any other exceptions are available like parse_error, type_error etc for web::json